# Better to use only client side data calls or a combination server side + client (hybrid approach)

Tags: c#, asp.net

It looks like the trend is moving away from server controls and towards client side service calls to populate your view.

That being said, I currently have a web application that uses all server side controls. I'm looking to improve performance and I know for doing follow up calls (once the page is loaded) via wcf/mvc will always win performance wise because it skips the page life cycle and doesn't have to update stuff needlessly.

But, if my page has to do an initial page lifecycle, wouldn't it make sense to go ahead and populate the controls data server side rather than letting the page load and then having to make another request to the server? This would seem slower to me although you could load stuff in pieces I guess. Maybe MVC solves this issue, but I use regular asp.net (with mvc only for certain service calls).

**So my question really is, does it really improve performance doing everything client side or does it make sense to do a hybrid approach like I mentioned above?** I am more concerned with my initial page load times than anything else.

Comment: You should profile your code and see what's the real source of the slow page load. Usually it will not be the server side controls, but rather database and web service calls that populate controls.

Comment: So I am confused as to what your real question is, the title of your question talks about choosing between pure web services or a combination of server-side controls plus web services. Then later you have in bold that your question really is should you do everything client-side or use a hybrid approach, does this hybrid approach involve sever-side controls at all or merely having the server-side build the view model?

Comment: Well client side yes, but I would be calling wcf/mvc services to get my data vs. just doing it on the initial page render server side.

Comment: I edited the question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But, if my page has to do an initial page lifecycle, wouldn't it make
>   sense to go ahead and populate the controls data server side rather
>   than letting the page load and then having to make another request to
>   the server?

Correct, you gain nothing by not populating the controls the first time you load the page, since as you say, you will still have to call the server to gather data and produce the appropriate markup. So a hybrid approach, in your scenario, makes sense as far as performance is concerned.

With that said, I think the hybrid approach, in general, tends to become cumbersome and you start getting issues with `ViewState` getting out of sync and what not. If you can avoid it, stick with pure MVC if you plan to do everything on the client side and do Ajax the "proper" way.

Comment: Looks like it's a trade off of clean code vs. a little extra performance boost.